# Regex to Skip One Digit and Extract All

Tags: python, pandas, extract

**Data**

```
  t=  pd.DataFrame({'A': ['3.1 Food', '3.1.1 Bread', '3.1.1.1 Chicken'], 'Val1': [10, 14, 94], 'Val2': [1,2,3], 'Val3' : [100, 120, 130]}, 
                      columns=['A', 'Val1'])

                 A  Val1
0         3.1 Food    10
1      3.1.1 Bread    14
2  3.1.1.1 Chicken    94
```

**Expected Output**

I'm trying to use conditional regular expressions to extract values and form a new column, with the output below. I'm only interested in values with the pattern **\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1}**

```
A              Val1   SubCategory
3.1 Food        10        nan
3.1.1 Bread     14    3.1.1 Bread
3.1.1.1 Chicken 94        nan
```

**What I've Tried**

```
t['SubCategory'] = t['A'].str.extract(r'^(\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1}.*)')

       A        Val1          SubCategory
3.1   Food       10           nan
3.1.1 Bread     14        3.1.1 Bread
3.1.1.1 Chicken 94      3.1.1.1 Chicken
```

I'm unable to restrict the regex such that it only looks into those with 3.1.1 only. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Hint: Notice the circumstances of your desired row: there are three numbers separated by dots, _and_ there is a start of line before, _and_ a space after.

Comment: Set a boundary `\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1}\b`...

Comment: @l'L'l A word boundary will match between a digit and a space just like it will match between a digit and a period, so it will still match `3.1.1` in `3.1.1.1`. Also, _even if_ that worked, your regexp would still match the `1.1.1` part of `3.1.1.1`, because there is nothing to anchor it at start.

Comment: @Amadan I'm still lost T.T

Comment: @Amadan: Using an assertion `^` would probably solve that issue.

Comment: @I'L'I I've tried using `r'^(\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1}^\b.*)')` and it doesn't work

Comment: @l'L'l The second one, yes. Note the "_even if_ it worked" part — this cannot be solved using `\b`.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes, I see now the boundary is useless — the assertion is key.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a space delimiter at the end:

```py
import pandas as pd


t=  pd.DataFrame({'A': ['3.1 Food', '3.1.1 Bread', '3.1.1.1 Chicken'], 'Val1': [10, 14, 94], 'Val2': [1,2,3], 'Val3' : [100, 120, 130]},
                      columns=['A', 'Val1'])
t['SubCategory'] = t['A'].str.extract(r'^(\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1})\s')

print(t)

                 A  Val1 SubCategory
0         3.1 Food    10         NaN
1      3.1.1 Bread    14       3.1.1
2  3.1.1.1 Chicken    94         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an assertion `^` at the start of the pattern should work:

```
^((?:\d\.){2}\d)[^.]
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/KucJkp/2

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment: Notice the circumstances of your desired row: there are three numbers separated by dots, and there is a start of line before, and a space after. You got the start anchor in your line of code, but not the end one.

```
t['SubCategory'] = t['A'].str.extract(r'^(\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1} .*)')
```

(If you just wanted to capture digits in a match, without a space, you would want to use a positive lookahead instead: `r'^(\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1})(?= )'`)

Comment: Doubtful they want the word after the digits to be captured as well (as the first pattern shows).

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, they want the pattern that captures the entire line. The parenthesised sentence was a hypothetical, showcasing the lookahead.

Comment: Ah, I see. It wasn't entirely clear from the question.